# Test case for fragment in android

Tags: android-fragments, junit, android-testing

In my application, I have multiple fragments on a single activity. Now I want to write a test case to check if these fragments are loading properly. To begin with, I passed some touch event to scroll to a particular fragment and then I am trying to fetch the name of this fragment. Below is my code for the test case:-

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> 
{
    MainActivity mMainActivity;
    ActionBar tactionbar;
    Fragment tFragment;


    public static final int TEST_POSITION = 2;
    private static String mSelection ;
    private int mPos = 0;




    public MainActivityTest()
    {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        super.setUp();
        mMainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        tactionbar = mfoneclay.getActionBar();
    }

    public void testPreConditions()
    {
        assertNotNull(mMainActivity);
        assertNotNull(tactionbar);
    }

    public void testFragmentUI()
     {
        mMainActivity.runOnUiThread(
                 new Runnable(){
                     public void run()
                     {  
                         mMainActivity.getCurrentFocus();

                     }
                 });

        for (int i = 1; i <= TEST_POSITION; i++) 
        {
          this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);
          mPos = tactionbar.getSelectedNavigationIndex();

        }

        this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);

        mSelection = (String)tactionbar.getTabAt(mPos).getText();



        String resultText = "Exclusive";

        assertEquals(resultText,mSelection);

      }

}
```

Here, "Exclusive" is the name of one of my tab to which I am navigating to via the touch event. Now, while running the test case, I can see that it is properly navigating to the "Exclusive" fragment, but the result shows the value of the msection variable as the name of the activity and not the fragments name. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. It was so stupid of me to use the wrong components to fetch the fragment. It turns out that I have to use "ViewPager" to fetch the fragments.